# Как справиться с длиннющим определением, мешающим смысловосприятию?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> В раннем Средневековье колоссальные развалины **уходящей цивилизации
>   времён расцвета Империи** наводнили обнищавшие горожане, разорившиеся
>   крестьяне, обездоленные, пришедшие сюда со всех сторон разлагающейся
>   страны, и конечно же, разбойники, с опустевших дорог.

Нет, если читается легко, я пойму.

Comment: Честно говоря, предложение вообще построено не осень удачно. Сначала читается так, будто сами развалины что-то там наводнили. И потом приходится перечитывать, чтобы понять кто на ком стоял.

Comment: Уже отправлено автору в Рим - он и комменты изучает. Спасибо! )))

Comment: @Сибиряк Верно, а исправить можно, перейдя в пассив (были наводнены)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такая игра "Где тут логика?"

Цивилизация времён расцвета Империи уходила в раннем Средневековье?  Если цивилизация существовала во времён расцвета Империи, то должна была уйти сразу "после рассвета", а не в раннем Средневековье. Многословие не есть многомыслие.

Чем отличаются "обнищавшие горожане и разорившиеся крестьяне" от "обездоленных", выделенных в отдельную "категорию"?

Странно, с одной стороны — движение со всех концов страны в сторону Рима (развалин), а с другой — опустевшие дороги?

И к чему это "конечно же" о разбойниках? Их перемещение понятней, логичней, чем судьбы других?

Comment: М_Г! Это ж не я придумываю проблемы! Я пытаюсь их решать, иногда с помощью сайта. Не полезу же с поиском логики к автору, историку искусств? У него на то научный редактор.

Comment: Думаю, научный редактор заблудился в нагромождении слов. Цивилизация **процветала**  во времён расцвета Империи, а **существовала** вплоть до Средних веков; в раннем средневековье она **уходила**. А если не так, тогда не **уходящая**, а **ушедшая** цивилизация.

Comment: И почему, "**конечно же**" разбойники? С ними  все понятней, чем с остальными?

Comment: *Конечно же* - как последняя капля, переполнившая чашу перечислений деклассированного элэмэнта. *Ушедшую* принимаю, мерси.

Comment: @М_Г Древнеримская цивилизация в раннем Средневековье была не ушедшей, а уходящей. Сохранялись многие элементы античной культуры (тот же латинский язык), но они постепенно вытеснялись обычаями пришедших варваров.

Comment: Ага! Это ценно! Благодарю!

Comment: @Марк Согласен (была не ушедшей, а уходящей).  Не согласен называть древнеримскую цивилизацию цивилизацией "расцвета Империи".

Answer (score 2):

В раннем Средневековье **колоссальные развалины уходящей цивилизации** наводнили обнищавшие горожане, разорившиеся крестьяне, обездоленные, пришедшие сюда со всех сторон разлагающейся страны, и конечно же, разбойники с опустевших дорог.

Надо убрать "времён расцвета Империи", а то управление  неясное. Три сочетания подряд в форме Р.п, их можно группировать по-разному. И неважно, кто читает книгу, смысл должен схватываться на лету.

И сочетание странное: **развалины, уходящей, расцвет**, всё это противоречиво по смыслу и напрягает слух.

Answer (score 1):

Мне как историку тут всё понятно: древнеримская цивилизация постепенно растворяется в средневековом варварстве.

Если книга на историков и ориентирована, то можно ничего не менять. Если же текст рассчитан на более массовую аудиторию, то, может быть, стоит конкретизировать. Что-то вроде **уходящей цивилизации времён расцвета Римской империи.**

Comment: Как историк, скажите, какими временными рамками ограничена указанная цивилизация? Как знаток русского языка, скажите, слова "цивилизация времён расцвета Римской империи" означают, что данная цивилизация исчезла с окончанием расцвета Римской империи? А это какие временные рамки? Нет ли противоречия? –

Comment: Думаю, как историк, Вы знаете, как было на самом деле, и подсознательно "подправляете" даже то, что выражено неверными словами, и не замечаете ошибки.

Comment: @М_Г как историк: Античная цивилизация появилась примерно в VIII в. до н. э. Упадок этой цивилизации начался где-то с III в. н. э. А влияние этой цивилизации сказывается до сих пор. Достаточно сказать. что последняя Римская империя исчезла только в 1806 г.
Как "знаток" - под цивилизацией здесь имеется в виду её первоначальное значение - Античные быт и культура. Они не исчезли вместе Западно-Римской империей, более того Восточно-Римская империя (Византия) продолжала существовать и восхищать западных королей аж до 1453 г.

Comment: Спасибо за историческую справку.  Но вот какой у меня вопросы: что это за "цивилизация времен расцвета Римской империи"? Почему именно расцвета? Ради красного словца?

Comment: @М_Г Культура времён расцвета Рима отличается от позднеримской. За основу того же латинского языка берут язык Цезаря и Цицерона, а не вульгарную латынь IV-V вв. В VIII веке наблюдалось так называемое Каролингское возрождение, когда Карл Великий и  его ближайшие потомки пытались восстановить цивилизационные элементы Римской империи, именно эпохи расцвета. В частности восстанавливали язык, музыку, литературу и даже государство, - Священно-Римская империя германской нации была создана именно тогда.

Comment: То есть "цивилизация времён расцвета Империи" — так можно называть этот период в развитии античной цивилизации?

Answer (score 0):

Да терпимо, запятая только мешает "разбойникам".

Comment: А вот и нет. Разбойники, оне повсюдова водятся, а "наши" - сугубо конкретные, *с опустевших дорог*.

Comment: То есть, опустевшие дороги - это место отправления разбойников? При первом прочтении вряд ли кто-нибудь так поймёт: вместе это читается как видоизменённое "разбойник с большой дороги". Поэтому запятая воспринимается как ошибка. Возможно, тире спасёт эту идею, поскольку "пришедшие" не повторено. Или добавить "те, что (с опустевших)".

Comment: Запятая мне не нравится. Мне кажется, и так понятно, без запятой: горожане из разрушенных городов, крестьяне из голодных сел, разбойники с опустевших дорог,